# WCF GET returning XML instead of JSON on server

Tags: json, xml, wcf, get

I have a WCF service with a webHttpBinding defined. The interface has a single method:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "*")]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Stream GetServerInfo();
```

Which returns a stream with encoded JSON:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        ServerData r = ServerData.Instance;
        r.upTime = (DateTime.Now - r._startupTime).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
        using (Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {
            r.usedMemory = ((double)proc.PrivateMemorySize64) / 1024 / 1024;
        }
        r.activeSessions = getServiceData().Count();
        string jsCode = "displayData" + "("+
            new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(r)
            +")";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/javascript";

        Console.WriteLine(jsCode);
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsCode));
```

When used on my devel PC it works fine. I get sth like:

```
displayData({"_startupTime":"\/Date(1435867525056)\/","serverVersion":"1.0.0.8","startUpTime":"2. 7. 2015 22:05:25","acceptedConnections":0,"upTime":"00.00:00:00","usedMemory":21.265625,"activeSessions":0})
```

However, after deploy to a remote server I get only following response and I want to get a JSON:

```
<GetServerInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetServerInfoResult>ZGlzcGxheURhdGEoeyJfc3RhcnR1cFRpbWUiOiJcL0RhdGUoMTQzNTg2ODUwMjc5NClcLyIsInNlcnZlclZlcnNpb24iOiIxLjAuMC44Iiwic3RhcnRVcFRpbWUiOiI3LzIvMjAxNSAxOjIxOjQyIFBNIiwiYWNjZXB0ZWRDb25uZWN0aW9ucyI6MCwidXBUaW1lIjoiMDAuMDA6MDA6MDAiLCJ1c2VkTWVtb3J5IjoyNy40NzY1NjI1LCJhY3RpdmVTZXNzaW9ucyI6MH0p</GetServerInfoResult></GetServerInfoResponse>
```

Note I call for the request locally directly on the server. But on remote call over network the response is the same. If I put a log output of the string to console I can see the output string is correct.
The config files are identical (except for addresses).

--edit
With the try-fail method I found out the string inside the XML response is the JSON string encoded in Base64.

Can somebody please help me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I did not find any solution. However, after restarting OS (Win Server 2012) and rebuilding it just works like a charm.